# PHP echo overwrites previous echo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have an HTML file that, when you click a button, Ajax loads a PHP file and the PHP file then echoes some text back to the HTML file.

The problem is that if I click the button a second time (or third, or fourth, etc), the next echoes overwrite the previous echo.

For example, if I click the button the first time, it would echo `text here`. If I click it a second time, it overwrites the previous echo and, again, would show `text here` instead of showing it on a new line.

Here's the HTML/Ajax:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="show-more-results"></div>
    <center><a class="btn show-more">Show more comments</a></center>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var videoid = <?php echo $video_id; ?>;

      $(document).ready(function() {    
        $(".show-more").click(function() {
          num_comments += 10;
          $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/misc/test.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {video_id: videoid, num: num_comments},
            success: function(data) {
              $("#show-more-results").html(data);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $videoid = $_POST['video_id'];
  $num_comments = $_POST['num'];

  echo $videoid;
?>
```

How can I make it so that the next echoes from the PHP file don't overwrite the previous echoes?

Comment: echoes do not overwrite each other

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `.html()` function, which will overwrite the contents of the element every time, use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add to it instead:

```
$("#show-more-results").append(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. :) Will mark as solved when I can (6 min).

Answer (score 1):

It's not PHP's `echo` that is overwriting your value, but your use of jQuerys [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function. It sets the HTML data for the element `#show-more-results` to a new value. (effectively overwriting the previous value)

To get the desired result, just concatenate the previous value with the new value:

```
$("#show-more-results").html(
      $("#show-more-results").html() + '<br />' + data
  );
```

Or even shorter:

```
$("#show-more-results").append('<br />' + data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$( "#show-more-results" ).append( "<p>" + data + "</p>" );
```

Wrapping the data in `<p>` tags will keep it neat, but you may want some other container.

Answer (score 0):

Every request is a separate script exectuion, it is like new page load.
You don't say, that HTML from previous page overwrites HTML from current page, do you?

If you want to preserve "history", you need to either accumulate reponses in your javascript code, or put in some persistent storage (Memcache, DB, etc) and return whole data.

Answer (score 0):

You should append the result instead of replacing it.

```
//This
$("#show-more-results").html(data);

should be
$("#show-more-results").append(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the success function, use document.createElement and createTextNode and appendChild to keep adding elements to the document.